# Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu and totally remove Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu on any media except floppy disks and old CD's (I mean, they have to be larger than around 1 GB and be bootable). You can see a tutorial here (but only follow until step 3): [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Then boot your media. You should see the options "Install Ubuntu" and "Try Ubuntu". You can select Install Ubuntu for a direct install, or Try Ubuntu which lets you try Ubuntu, and if you want to install it there's an shortcut on the desktop to install it. When you get to the partition part, there should be an option saying "Remove Windows and install Ubuntu" (not sure exactly) with a message under it about something critical. Select it, and if the option isn't there, select the option "Something else" and delete the partitions that Windows uses (not your partitions with data, files, pictures, etc.) and make these 2 partitions:

1: A ext4 filesystem one, and set the mount point to /. Install Ubuntu on that partition.

2: This is not needed, but make a swap partition, which is a simple partition: A swap filesystem one. Make it as big as you want (but you should use something like 8-16 GB). Instead of using RAM, Ubuntu uses swap which is a kind of "RAM partition". You only need 1 swap partition if you have 2 Linux OS'es. You don't need swap, but it is highly recommended.

Configure the rest of the installation now.

Once you've done the install, reboot.